# C Login system that checks if user is Admin/Staff from separate files

Tags: c, file, authentication

Hoping anyone can help or post their correct implementation...

- I have a function that reads two files, Admin & Staff.
- I am accessing these files using **fread** to check whether Admin/Staff during login.
- If credentials entered incorrectly it prompts user to re-login.
- The problem is even if I entered the correct credentials, it still prompts user to re-login.

I dunno if my logic is properly executed here:

```
void loginPage(){
 char username[30], password[20];
 int i, result = 0 ,size = 0;

 struct form login;
 
 FILE *admin;
 FILE *staff;

 //Opening files for read-------------------
 admin = fopen("adminAcc.txt", "r");
 staff = fopen("ordinaryUsers.txt", "r");
 
 //login---------------------------------
 printf("\nLogin Page");
 printf("\n================");
 printf("\nEnter Username: \n");
 fflush(stdin);
 gets(username);
 printf("Enter Password: \n");
 fflush(stdin);
 gets(password);

//check admin----------------------------------
 while(fread(&login, sizeof(struct form), 1, admin)){
   if(strcmp(login.roles, "Admin") == 0){
     if(strcmp(username, login.username) == 0 && strcmp(password, login.password) == 0){
       system("cls");
       adminPage();
     }else{
       relogin();
     }
   }else{
     break;
   }
 }
 fclose(admin);

//check staff-------------------------------------
 while(fread(&login, sizeof(struct form), 1, staff)){
   if(strcmp(login.roles, "OU") == 0){
     if(strcmp(login.status, "Disable") == 0){
       printf("\nPlease wait for Admin to verify the account!");
       getch();
       system("cls");
       main();
     }else if(strcmp(username, login.username) == 0 && strcmp(password, login.password) == 0){
       system("cls");
       OUsersPage();
     }else{
       relogin();
     }
   }
 }
 fclose(staff);
}
```

Comment: Show us the admin and user account files please. Exactly as they are formatted in the files.

Comment: Looks like you're only checking the first entry and then deciding if they can login or not. If there are more than one record in each file you need to restructure the loop to read and test all of them before you decide none match. If there aren't more than one record per file then the loop isn't required.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but I would guess at some point you're going to run into issues calling things recursively and unwinding them properly at the end. You might consider a different approach. Like when you call `adminPage();` and then return from that you're still in the loop.

Comment: You must check if open succeeded. You must not use `gets`.

Comment: this is how my user info is stored (same for staff): 
[admin](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/884808422523039807/1056968745219805225/image.png)
@TheNomad

Comment: ```fflush(stdin)``` is undefined behaviour. *"Once the abstract state machine reaches an undefined state, no further assumption about the continuation of the execution can be made."*

Comment: Why even work on a ```FILE *``` when ```fopen``` might have failed?

Comment: ```gets```? What is that function? It's not part of the C standard, as far as I know.  Is there no limitation to how far it will read? I believe it could result in an overflow. Use ```fgets``` instead.

Comment: ```getch``` is not part of the C standard either. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: The call to ```main``` is not something I have ever seen, but it looks suspicious.

Comment: `getch` just allows the program to pause and proceed to function call by pressing any key @Haris